# Is there any compatability issue while migrating jasper reports 0.4.0(ireports 0.4.0) to jasper reports 5.6.0

Tags: jasper-reports

Wee are using old version of jasper reports  0.4.0, planned to migrate to jasper reports 5.6.0. Is there any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will tell you whether compatibility issues are there or not

https://github.com/nblock/jasperstarter/blob/master/CHANGES